# Not able to handle multiple post request on the same page

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have code which should handle multiple post request on the same page. It has two button in the HTML page inside a single form. It is taking the post value from first button, but not the second. I have no idea why, when I include the second button and click on first, it says the second button is not found. Can anyone please help me solve this issue?

**index.html**

```
 <input type="submit" style="background-color:#FFFF66;color:black;width:150px; height:40px;" name="ServerDetails" value="ServerDetails"/>
   
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" style="background-color:#FFFF66;color:black;width:150px; height:40px;" name="GenerateFile" value="GenerateFile"/>
```

**views.py**

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['ServerDetails']:
            print("Inside Server Details")
            

        if request.POST['GenerateFile']:
           filename = request.POST['patchconfigofpg3']
           print(filename)
```

**models.py**

```
class course(models.Model):
    patchconfigofpg3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

When I click on the first button it is throwing me the below error:
[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

just change

```
if request.POST['ServerDetails']:
```

to

```
if request.POST.get('ServerDetails',False):
```

and do same for other button

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you write `request.POST['ServerDetails']` and `request.POST['GenerateFile']`. Bascially you try to access the key on the `QueryDict` but this key does not exist giving you an error. Instead you should use the `in` operator:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'ServerDetails' in request.POST:
        print("Inside Server Details")
    if 'GenerateFile' in request.POST:
        filename = request.POST['patchconfigofpg3']
        print(filename)
```